# Disable output of hardcoded HTML tags in a PHP file

Tags: php, html

I am working with a software written in PHP that I have no control over. Some of the PHP files have hardcoded HTML tags in them that I'd like to suppress or exchange with my own code.

Fortunately there is a plugin-system that allows me to execute my own code at certain points, here's an example of the files I'm dealing with:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <?php
    execute_plugin_code_1()
  ?>
  <head>
  <!-- some additional tags -->
  </head>
  <?php
    execute_plugin_code_2()
  ?>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

What I want to do here is generate my own `<head>` tag. I don't want to alter the file itself so I'd like to suppress the hardcoded tag and its children.

Is there any way to disable the output of hardcoded HTML between `execute_plugin_code_1()` and `execute_plugin_code_2()`?

Comment: If you can get something in before the first <!DOCTYPE... tag,  you can use ob_start to put in a callback function and parse the entire page before it is sent.

Comment: Wouldn't you just be able to `echo '<!--';` at the end of `execute_plugin_code_1()` and then add `echo '-->';` at the beginning of `execute_plugin_code_2()`? That should comment out the head and children using html comments

Comment: @kainaw Thanks, that might work. I'll look into that.

Comment: @JiFus Yeah, thought about that, felt a bit hackish, but at least it's the most simple solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question, no, you cannot "disable" the HTML tags. You would need to remove them from the file, or use an entirely different file. The structure of this file is pretty odd though. I'm not sure what the original developer was trying to allow by providing hooks that run just before, and just after the head of the HTML document. It would have made much more sense to provide a hook within the head and within the body.

Comment: As stated in a prior comment, you certainly can wrap the head tags in an HTML comment utilizing the provided hooks.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I feared. As for the hooks: I did simplify the structure of the file (obviously): There are hooks inside the head and the body on top if those I included in my example.

Answer (score -1):

Do you want to avoid jquery? If not, then

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('head').remove();
)};
```

https://api.jquery.com/remove/

Then you'd need to also use jquery to insert your new head tag's html. I'd be very wary, though. Seems like it'd be pretty easy to break the page altogether.